# Page do not show content in WordPress, for no reason

Tags: php, wordpress

well, I have a somewhat unusual problem for me. 
I am making a website in WordPress however when I created the template page, the content does not show, show title, date, etc., however nothing is in content

The site is: http://estudiovitamina.com/clients/viamanzoni/

page url: http://estudiovitamina.com/clients/viamanzoni/info/

And the page.php :

```
<?php get_header();?>
<?php /* include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/menu.php'); */ ?>
<div id="content">
<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
<?php the_title(); ?>

<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php the_permalink(); ?>

<?php
$page = get_page_by_title( 'info' );
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $page->post_content); 
echo $content;
?>
<?php endwhile; else:?>
<?php endif;?> 
</div>

<?php get_footer();?>
```

Comment: why are you `wp_reset_query()` three times? The Loop will never start because you reset the query and then never make a new query

Comment: @celeriko Desperate times, I had not noticed, I already removed.